# Adding sub-view to UINavigationBar makes UINavigationItem non-touchable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm adding a blur effect to UINavigationController (for reason I need it custom) - I'm using following codes and it adds the blur effect expectedly to navigationController:

[image]

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
navBar.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
navBar.shadowImage = nil;
navBar.translucent = YES;

UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -25, navBar.bounds.size.width, navBar.bounds.size.height+25);

[navBar insertSubview:visualEffectView atIndex:0];
```

Although, I can see blur has added and all the navigation items, back arrow is not anymore clickable. If I stops 'visualEffectView' from adding, then back arrow starts work again.

Answer (score 0):

Add UIView On Navigation Bar

```
UIView *NavView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 44)];
NavView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
NavView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:NavView];
```

Comment: If I don't use `insertSubview: atIndex:`, the view covers all the navigation items except back arrow button. However I see (with my original code), if I add custom UIBarButtonItems at right - they're tappable! But back arrow - not, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cover your Button.

Try this:

```
[self.view insertSubview:visualEffectView belowSubview:yourBackButton];
```

insert `visualEffectView` or `navBar`

EDIT:
Try this:

```
[navBar insertSubview:visualEffectView belowSubview:navBar.backItem.copy];
```

Comment: I need the view to be added in UINavigationBar as it has animations to move up and down, and I want the new view also appear or disappears with it's parent.

Comment: Your button where is ? In your navigationBar or in self.view?

Comment: Its regular back button of UINavigationController. If I adds extra UIBarButtonItem in navigationItem at right, that seems tappable but back button.

Comment: Just try to addSubview again your back button after  you create your blurEffect.

Comment: [navBar addSubview:yourBackButton]; Create your button like outlet view first.

Comment: I actually didn't wanted adding custom back button again except using the in-built one. This extra the works. But if I wouldn't have any option, then I'll have to do it.

Comment: you can't hide that backButton and add a custom backButton from storyboard?

Comment: Yes, as I told that is my last option. But I wanted to use default back button as provided by navigationController class itself.

Comment: New code is creating warning now: `Incompatible pointer types sending 'UINavigationItem * _Nullable' to parameter of type 'UIView * _Nonnull'`. I tried to set `belowSubView:` with other probabilities, but didn't worked!

Comment: try "navBar.backItem.copy"

Comment: Unfortunately, this thrown me exception: "[UINavigationItem copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c999ab0"

Comment: I finally able to make this work with default back arrow button by disabling user interaction to my custom view: `visualEffectView.userInteractionEnabled = false;` (per my original code). But appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

I finally able to make this work with default back arrow button by disabling user interaction to my custom view:

```
visualEffectView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

(per my original code).